# chaining await with .then and try catch syntax

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, async-await

I have a submit function

```
const onSubmit = async (creditCardInput) => {
const { navigation } = this.props;
this.setState({ submitted: true });
let creditCardToken;

try {
  creditCardToken = await getCreditCardToken(creditCardInput);
  if (creditCardToken.error) {
    this.setState({ submitted: false});
    return;
  }
} catch (e) {
  this.setState({ submitted: false });
  return;
}


try {
  const obj = await subscribeUser(creditCardToken);
  console.log('returned obj', obj);
  try {
    const docRef = await this.db.collection("users").doc(this.user.email).set({
      id: this.user.uid,
      subscriptionId: obj.customerId,
      active: true
    });
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef);
    this.navigateToScreen('HomeScreen');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error adding document: ", e);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('catch error', error);
  this.setState({ submitted: false, error: SERVER_ERROR, message: error });
}  
};
```

This is working as suspected - when this.db.collection call fails the catch is implemented meaning it logs out "Error adding document: ", e
see code snippet below

```
  try {
    const docRef = await this.db.collection("users").doc(this.user.email).set({
      id: this.user.uid,
      subscriptionId: obj.customerId,
      active: true
    });
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef);
    this.navigateToScreen('HomeScreen');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error adding document: ", e);
  }
```

However when I implement the subscribe user function in a different manner (see below) I'm no longer using try catch but rather .then on await the inner function ends up failing and the outside catch statement is executed meaning it logs out console.log('catch error', error); when it should be logging out console.log("Error adding document: ", errors);
why is that? shouldn't they work in the same way meaning the code snippet above and below should work in the same manner 
see code below

```
await subscribeUser(creditCardToken).then((obj)=> {
this.db.collection("users").doc(this.user.email).set({
    id: this.user.uid,
    subscriptionId: obj.customerId,
    active: true
}).then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef);
    this.navigateToScreen('HomeScreen');
}).catch((errors) => {
    console.log("Error adding document: ", errors);
});
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('catch error', error);
    this.setState({ submitted: false message: error });
});
```

Just an added note when this.db.collections resolves successfully the .then executes the way it should meaning it logs out with console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef) however like I said before if it's rejected the outer catch is executed and not the inner catch

Also adding return to the this.db.collection function and removing await has no effect on outcome

Comment: Have you considered with that last bit of code to use indentation a little better - as it is it looks like one flat chain of .then/.catch/.catch when clearly it isn't

Comment: try `return this.db.collection("users") ....` to see if it makes a difference

Comment: by the way, it's hardly ever "correct" to use async/await AND .then/.catch simultaneously like that

Comment: had trouble indenting on SO didn't copy well from editor - I will try return this and in terms of "correct" way I understand using try catch is better with async and await but they should work the same way as promises so even thought it might not be correct I'm thinking it should still function the same

Comment: the missing `return` may make all the difference - have you tried it?

Comment: How exactly does `this.db.collection("users").doc(…).set(…)` fail? If it does synchronously throw an exception (which it should not!), your outer `catch` callback would indeed get triggered. If it did return a promise that gets rejected, your code should work as expected.

Comment: When I add the return statement the outside catch is triggering not the the inside catch which I find odd  but when I use a try catch within a try catch it's working as expected

Comment: I'm guessing using a regular promise nested within an async function works differently?  Not sure why though so just trying to solve that mystery

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this - convert your `set` function to use async/await syntax, or *return* your set function to the `subscribeUser` function's next *then* statement. I'll show both, but I prefer the second as I don't like mixing async/await with then/catch.

```js
const tempThis = this
subscribeUser(creditCardToken).then((obj)=> {
  // RETURN this promise and you'll get it in the next then statement
  return tempThis.db.collection("users").doc(tempThis.user.email).set({
    id: tempThis.user.uid,
    subscriptionId: obj.customerId,
    active: true
  })
}).then((docRef) => {
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef);
  this.navigateToScreen('HomeScreen');
}).catch((errors) => {
  // This will catch the errors from subscribeUser AND from the set function
  console.log("Error adding document: ", errors);
});
```

or using just async/await

```js
try {
  const obj = await subscribeUser(creditCardToken)
  const docRef = await this.db.collection("users").doc(this.user.email).set({
    id: this.user.uid,
    subscriptionId: obj.customerId,
    active: true
  })
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef);
  this.navigateToScreen('HomeScreen');
} catch (error) {
  // Handle your errors
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I will test - it shouldn't matter though if you use keyword await or not in theory you should still be able to chain no?  Meaning the .then was working with await

Comment: True, but your "set" function returns a promise so you need to return that to the outer function. That's why your code isn't waiting for it to finish and why it's blowing right by the inner then/catch. For 99% of use cases (and probably 100% of yours and mine), async/await vs then/catch is personal preference. I just personally don't like mixing chaining with async/await - again, personal preference.

Comment: I agree as well - I'm more experimenting than anything - the try catch syntax is working for me as expected but wondering why you can chain await but it may work differently than regular promises

Comment: You can chain multiple `then` statements, but `catch` with async will go to your `try`/`catch`. So you could do:
const docRef = await subscribeUser(creditCardToken).then((obj)=> {
  return this.db.collection("users").doc(this.user.email).set({
    id: this.user.uid,
    subscriptionId: obj.customerId,
    active: true
  })
})

Comment: Hi I'm Joe Too - I tried the code above using regular promises within the async function and I'm still getting the same result even when I add return and remove await - the inside promise is making the outside promise fail

Comment: I just updated the answer slightly. When you run the `set` code, the scope of `this` is changed - it's no longer `this` from the outer function, but `this` from the promise result. So you need to hoist it up to access `this.db` and `this.user`. This is likely what is throwing the error - that `this.db` and `this.user` don't exist in your outer promise result, which throws an error, which is then why your catch is getting the error from the outside promise.

Comment: the context of this should be fine as it's not throwing a context error - the inside promise is causing the outside catch statement to be invoked -  but I will give it a whirl - again I'm getting same error the context of this is fine since I'm using arrow functions

Comment: Also when I put the correct information in .then functions properly I updated the original question with this fact